# Experiencing high CPU usage

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, cpu

I am on **Ubuntu 20.04** (Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic) and have been experiencing **high CPU usage** (30-40%); even when I'm just looking at my desktop without any applications open in the background.

I have recently made two changes to my system:

1. Upgraded RAM (Previously had 4GB, added an 8GB stick)
2. Installed Windows 10 (Dual-Boot)

And I believe it is after I dual-booted windows I'm facing this issue. I can hear my fans all cranked up, this wasn't an issue before.

### Update:

**I also updated the BIOS after installing windows, maybe that is the cause of the issue?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Execute `top` on terminal and add the screenshot of that.

Comment: Have updated the post with the result of top command

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: @heynnema I just checked and somehow it got enabled after a bios update I did. I've now disabled it and the CPU usage is back to normal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System Monitor**

In `System Monitor` enable **All Processes** for a more complete look...

[image]

Or use the `top` command in the `terminal`.

**Memory**

In order to take the speed advantage of memory interleaving, memory DIMMs should always be configured in equal size/type DIMM pairs. With 4G, you should have either added another 4G DIMM, or replaced it with two 8G DIMMs.

**Windows**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**Update #1:**

From the comments... Turned off Secure Boot in the BIOS, and it's working fine now.

Comment: as suggested by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269203/experiencing-high-cpu-usage?noredirect=1#comment2149007_1269203) comment, my secure boot was enabled. After disabling it everything seems to be normal.